# How to fetch single row/data from Mysql_fetch_array?

Tags: mysql, magento, row, fetch, fgetcsv

I am reading .csv file through PHP using fgetcsv(). Now I am able to fetch I mean read data from .csv file.
Then I need to check SKU column with my fetch result & accordingly have to perform either Insertion Or Updation. 
Suppose SKU is already present there, then I have to update my row in table else I need to insert new record.
I have write following code...Plz check n tell me where I am doing mistake-:

```
<?php
$row = 1; 
if (($handle = fopen("localhost/data/htdocs/magento/var/import/Price.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) 
{     
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 8000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {         
        $num = count($data);         
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";           
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) 
        {             
            $temp = $data;             
            $string = implode(";", $temp);           
        }
            $pieces = explode(";", $string);             
            $col1 = $pieces[0];  
            $col2 = $pieces[1];
            $col3 = $pieces[2];      
            $col4 = $pieces[3];             

            $db_name = "magento";
                        $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "magento", "password");
                     If (!$con)
            {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                mysql_close($con);
            }
            $seldb = mysql_select_db($db_name, $con);

            $query_fetch = "SELECT `sku` from `imoprt_prices`";
            $result_fetch = mysql_query($query_fetch);
            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result_fetch); 

            for($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) 
            { 
                $value = mysql_result($result_fetch, i, 'sku');
                if(strcmp('".$value."', '".$col2."') == 0)
                {               
                    $flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    $flag = 0;
                        break;
                }
            }
                if($flag == 1)
                {
                    $query_upadte = "(UPDATE imoprt_prices SET customer_id= '".$col1."', sku ='".$col2."', price= '".$col3."', website= '".$col4."'
                    )";
                    mysql_query($query_upadte);
                        $row++;         
                }
                if($flag == 0)
                {
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `imoprt_prices`(`customer_id`,`sku`,`price`,`website`) VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."')");
                    $row++;   
                } 

    } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Do you have a unique index on SKU to avoid duplicates? Or would it be possible to add one?

Comment: SKU is unique...thats why need to update for existing SKUs..

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you run it ?

Comment: Do you have a unique key defined on the SKU column ?

Comment: no...I have not defined Unique for SKU column... There are so many rows get inserted in thousands whether .CSV file contains only 20. Shall I make SKU as unique? N my guess is it is not going for Update statement means it always checks Flag=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an actual `UNIQUE` index on your `imoprt_prices` table, you can use the [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax and simplify your code a bit to something similar to; (note, can't test, so see as pseudo code)

```
$db_name = "magento";
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "magento", "password") or die(mysql_error());
$seldb = mysql_select_db($db_name, $con);

if (($handle = fopen("localhost/data/htdocs/magento/var/import/Price.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) 
{     
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 8000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        $col1 = $pieces[0];  
        $col2 = $pieces[1];
        $col3 = $pieces[2];      
        $col4 = $pieces[3]; 

        $query_upadte = "INSERT INTO imoprt_prices (customer_id, sku, price, website) ".
            "VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."') ".
            "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE customer_id='".$col1."', price='".$col3.
            "',website='".$col4."'";
        mysql_query($query_upadte);
    }
}
```

You may also want to either [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or use parameterized queries to make sure there's no `'` in your inserted values though. That is always a danger with building sql strings like this.

Simple demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b37f/3).

Comment: Hi, Do u mean to set UNIQUE index for whole table import_prices or just UNIQUE constraint for SKU column as i.e. the column we are checking for condition..

Comment: @Prat Just for `SKU`. What `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` does is try to insert, and if the insert fails due to a unique index (SKU being duplicated) it instead updates the existing row.

Answer (score 1):

In the following snippet:

```
$query_upadte = "UPDATE imoprt_prices SET customer_id= '".$col1."', sku ='".$col2."', price= '".$col3."', website= '".$col4."'";
```

You're trying to update all the rows repeatedly, instead of just updating a single row. This is normally not allowed in MySQL. You need to specify a particular `unique` ID to be updated.

Comment: I am checking condion in If() & then setting flag to fire update query.